# binding error in l-value reference and r-value reference

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

```
void f(int & i){
    cout << "l-value-ref" << endl;
}

void f(int && i){
    cout << "r-value-ref" << endl;
}
```

Assuming the code above, we have a overloaded function which takes respectively l-value-reference and r-value-reference parameters.

```
int x = 5;
f(x);
f(5);
const int j = 9;
f(j);
```

when i use **const int j = 9** compiler gives ambiguity error. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Change the first `f()` to take a `const int &i` parameter.

Comment: I'm surprised your compiler gives you that error. Mine gives me "binding const int to reference of type int& discards qualifiers".

Comment: If it gives *ambiguity* error, then I think this error is **misleading** because neither of them can be invoked with argument `j` which is of type `int const`. The compiler should give *"no function found which accepts `int const &`"*.

Comment: Or add a `void f(const int &)` overload. Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: but it seems that the compiler can not differentiate the r value and l value when it comes to `const`parameters am i right?

Comment: @RıfatTolgaKiran, no, neither of these functions is going to work. You can easily check it by commenting them 1by1. Neither of the overloads match the `const int` argument.\

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall oh is my fault. the compiler gives `error: binding 'const int' to reference of type 'int&' discards qualifiers` error. So the only solution is to create a `const int &` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your compiler error (if it is indeed the one you mentioned) is misleading. What is really wrong here is that attempting to pass a `const int` argument to any of your functions would discard the `const` qualifier, which is not allowed. You can solve it by either changing the signature to `const int&` / `const int&&` (note that `const int&&` will still not work with a `const int` argument), or by adding an another overload for `const` arguments, depending on what exactly do you want to achieve.

Basically the choice you have to make is between "I need one version that needs to be able to modify the passed reference" (2 versions then) and "I will never modify the passed reference anyway" (just the `const int&` version).